# Tiling window manager using mouse only

Tags: window-manager, tiling-wm

I am looking for a way to define a grid and use the *middle mouse button only*, to drag a window into a specific area and resize it. Nothing I found seems to be able to do this.

Specifically I am looking for something that works similar to GridMove:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfoGHc89WFM

I want to emphasize that I do not want to use the keyboard. No superkey/ctrl/alt/shift + mouse button but *only* a specified mouse button that I can hold over a window and drag.

I don't care if this is realized in a desktop environment, Compiz or in another program (I'd prefer several options though). My favorite desktop environment is Cinnamon but I would abandon it for this feature.

Multi monitor support would be good.

Comment: If noone knows a tiling window manager that emulates this behaviour, then you will have to start trying them out yourself. There's a collection of examples on Wikipedia, and a sort of comparison of many here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Comparison_of_tiling_window_managers

Comment: I already did. I looked into docs of the most popular window managers and tried some of them. They all don't quite do what I want. Of course I don't know the docs of all of them by heart so I might have missed stuff.

Comment: Keys can usually be configured, so if you find anything that does it (even with a keyboard) you might be able to just re-bind it to a mouse action of your choice.

Comment: This behavior does not make sense using a keyboard. With a keyboard you usually would say "if this combination is pressed, go to upper left corner". But in my scenario where the window should be resized is defined during the action. So the concept is completely different. In cases where a keyboard and mouse combination is used, I never see a way to disable the super key.

Comment: Under what window manager? The way to do it is completely dependent on the window manager. Some window managers are programmable, so if they don't have the right command built in you can program them. Others would require modifying the window manager source code.

Comment: I tried to make it work with i3.

Comment: @Gilles I believe the implication was "under _any_ window manager," i.e. dealer's choice.

Comment: I'd prefer "under any window manager" but I could settle for one window manager for now.